# Python pandas: create new column based on max value within group, but using value from additional (string) column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'group_id': [1,1,2,2], 
                   'name':['Arthur','Bob','Caroline','Denise'],
                   'income': [40000, 20000,50000,60000]
                   })

df
Out[94]: 
   group_id      name  income
0         1    Arthur   40000
1         1       Bob   20000
2         2  Caroline   50000
3         2    Denise   60000
```

My desired output is to have, within group_id, the name of the person with the highest income, e.g.:

```
df
Out[94]: 
   group_id      name  income   highest_income_name
0         1    Arthur   40000                Arthur
1         1       Bob   20000                Arthur
2         2  Caroline   50000                Denise
3         2    Denise   60000                Denise
```

Based on the data-generating process for my actual data, there will always be only one name within a group with the highest income.

What is the best practice way for generating the above?

If I try to fill in the max income and then find the name, I'm stuck with NaN, which I potentially can try to fill in but would additional complexity.

```
df['max_income'] = df.groupby('group_id')['income'].transform('max')
df['highest_income_name'] = df['name'][df['income']==df['max_income']]

df
Out[105]: 
   group_id      name  income  max_income highest_income_name
0         1    Arthur   40000       40000              Arthur
1         1       Bob   20000       40000                 NaN
2         2  Caroline   50000       60000                 NaN
3         2    Denise   60000       60000              Denise
```

Comment: Get the index of max of income in the groupby. Use that to get the name using iloc

Comment: what if there is two the highest income?

Comment: Based on the data-generating process for my actual data, there will always be only one name within a group with the highest income, so I can check that that is true and then not have to handle the case where there is a tie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
In [287]: import numpy as np

In [302]: df['highest_income_name'] = np.where(df.income.eq(df.groupby('group_id')['income'].transform(max)), df.name, np.nan)

In [308]: df['highest_income_name'] = df.groupby('group_id')['highest_income_name'].transform('first')

In [309]: df
Out[309]: 
   group_id      name  income highest_income_name
0         1    Arthur   40000              Arthur
1         1       Bob   20000              Arthur
2         2  Caroline   50000              Denise
3         2    Denise   60000              Denise
```

Comment: does max here doesnt prevent this operation of being vectorized?